# How to change TO_DAYS and CURRENT_DATE to another calendar in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, calendar, sql-timestamp

There are two methods in mysql to get current date.

**TO_DAYS()** //  Return the date argument converted to days  [Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days)

**CURRENT_DATE()** //  Synonyms for CURDATE()  [Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date)

Here's the question:

> **Is it possible to change CURRENT_DATE to another calendar date in**
>   **mysql?**

For example: Current Date (Y) is 2015 but Current Date (Y) is different in other calendars like Hebrew calendar or Arabic Calendar or etc...

How to do it?

***Note:*** Please do not mention about PHP Function to change date, cause those methods don't work into mysql, I mean it just **CONVERT** Gregorian calendar to other calendars **not change**!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> Is it possible to change CURRENT_DATE to another calendar date in mysql?

No, MySQL does not do this. You might consider contributing a [user-defined function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-functions.html) to do it.